# Imgur API mangles payloads containing an emoji

Tags: curl, imgur

Using this command:

```sh
curl \
--request POST \
'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/abc123' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer secret' \
--form 'Hello  World'
```

Imgur's API responds with a 200, so I expect the description of the image to be `Hello  World`.  If I then issue a GET request with the API:

```sh
curl \
--request GET \
'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/abc123' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer secret'
```

I see this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "description": "Hello ? World",
        "edited": "0"
    },
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
}
```

<sup>(some payload omitted for brevity)</sup>

Additionally, if I look at the image on Imgur's site I also see `Hello ? World`.

[Imgur's API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/) don't suggest adding a content encoding to any payload.  I've tried adding my own header:

```sh
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

and the `?` remains.

How can I get Imgur's API to retain the emoji?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't a restriction of the API but the Imgur UI as well